# How To Draw Multi Column ListView in WM_DRAWITEM

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, win32gui

I have a 3-column ListView (I didn't include the columns and items insertion code below since these parts work):

```
hwndListbox = CreateWindow(
                WC_LISTVIEW, 
                "", 
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT|LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, 
                100, 100,600, 300, 
                hwnd, 
                (HMENU)1, 
                NULL, 
                NULL);
```

Now I am trying to use `WM_DRAWITEM` to change the background colors based on the text in the 1st column:

```
    case  WM_DRAWITEM:
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)(lParam);
        HDC hDC = pDIS->hDC;
        RECT rc = pDIS->rcItem;
        // initialize brushes
        HBRUSH bgRed = CreateSolidBrush (RGB(255,0,0));
        HBRUSH bg = (HBRUSH)(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
        // declare strings for the sub-items' text
        TCHAR  text_col1[256];
        TCHAR  text_col2[256];
        TCHAR  text_col3[256];
        // get the text from sub-items
        ListView_GetItemText( pDIS -> hwndItem , pDIS -> itemID , 0 ,text_col1, 256);
        ListView_GetItemText( pDIS -> hwndItem , pDIS -> itemID , 1 ,text_col2, 256);
        ListView_GetItemText( pDIS -> hwndItem , pDIS -> itemID , 2 ,text_col3, 256);
        // fill the row
        if(strcmp(text_col1,"Random_Name") == 0)
        {
            FillRect(hDC,&rc,bgRed);
        }
        else
        {
            FillRect(hDC,&rc,bg);
        }
        // How to draw text of 2nd and 3rd columns within columns' boundaries?
        DrawText(hDC, text_col1, strlen(text_col1), &rc, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_LEFT);
    }
    return 0;
```

How do I draw the text of 2nd and 3rd columns? I can call `DrawText()` with the other strings, but since they're all drawn onto the same rectangle, they don't conform to the column boundaries, but instead move freely across the rectangle depending on the format flags I specify in the last argument. How do I overcome this issue?

If there is a way to either get the same effect without using `WM_DRAWITEM`, or alternatively, define each column as a separate rectangle or any other solution, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Unrelated, prevent leaks by calling `DeleteObject(bgRed);` when you no longer need that brush.

Comment: @ Barmak Shemirani, Thanks, noted. should I not delete `bg` since it is a stock object, am I right?

Comment: Yes, `bg` is fine, don't try to delete it.

Comment: Using `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` is arguably easier for a listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ListView_GetSubItemRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_getsubitemrect) macro to retrieve subitem's rect.

```cpp
void ListView_GetSubItemRect(
   hwnd,
   iItem,
   iSubItem,
   code,
   prc
);
```